# Force ImageView to maintain a predeterminate size

Tags: android, view

I have a View that I need to force to always have a certain size.

I create the view dynamically like this:

```
    Drawable sunDrawable = getActivity().getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.img_sun);//Drawable to use as background

    if(sunDrawable != null)
    {
        int drawableWidth = sunDrawable.getIntrinsicWidth();
        int drawableHeight = sunDrawable.getIntrinsicHeight();
        final float ratioWidth = drawableWidth * ratio;//Ratio is a variable calculated based on the original design, in this case is 1.44f
        final float ratioHeight = drawableHeight * ratio;

        Log.e(
                "Sun D size",
                "WxH: " + drawableWidth + "x" + drawableHeight
        );//This prints 1335 x 1335
        Log.e(
                "Sun DR size",
                "WxH: " + ratioWidth + "x" + ratioHeight
        );//This prints 1922.4 x 1922.4

        final View sunImageView = new View(getActivity());
        RelativeLayout.LayoutParams sunParams = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(
                (int)ratioWidth,
                (int)ratioHeight
        );
        sunImageView.setLayoutParams(sunParams);
        sunImageView.setBackground(sunDrawable);

        sunImageView.getViewTreeObserver().addOnGlobalLayoutListener(
                new ViewTreeObserver.OnGlobalLayoutListener()
                {
                    @Override
                    public void onGlobalLayout()
                    {
                        //sunImageView.getViewTreeObserver().removeOnGlobalLayoutListener(this);
                        Log.e(
                                "Sun size",
                                "WxH: " + sunImageView.getWidth() + "x" + sunImageView.getHeight()
                        );//This prints 1080x1922
                    }
                }
        );

        parallaxContainerRelativeLayout.addView(sunImageView);//RelativeLayout

        sunImageView.setX(displaySize.x - (sunParams.width / 2));//DisplaySize is 1080x1920
        sunImageView.setY(getYForScrollView(-sunParams.height / 4, sunParams.height));//getYForScrollView returns the inverted Y (0 is max height, max height is 0)
```

As you can see by the comments on the code, after the layout is drawn the `View` resizes itself to 1080x1922 instead of the size I explicitly set (1922x1922).
I tried setting the `minimumWidth` but it didn't make any difference.

I also tried resetting the size on the `onGlobalLayout()` call, but it keeps reseting its size to 1080x1922, which causes an "infinite" number of calls to `onGlobalLayout()`.

Is there a way to force the `View`'s size?

**UPDATE**

Current testing device: Nexus 5 (1080x1920)

Layout XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@android:color/transparent"
    android:clipToPadding="false"
    android:clipChildren="false">

    <com.walkme.wordgalaxy.views.map.ExposedScrollView
        android:id="@+id/parallaxScrollView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:scrollbars="none"
        android:clipToPadding="false"
        android:clipChildren="false">

        <!-- The sunImageView is added to this Widget -->
        <RelativeLayout
            android:id="@+id/parallaxContainerRelativeLayout"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:clipToPadding="false"
            android:clipChildren="false">

        </RelativeLayout>

    </com.walkme.wordgalaxy.views.map.ExposedScrollView>

    <com.walkme.wordgalaxy.views.map.ExposedScrollView
        android:id="@+id/planetScrollView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:scrollbars="none"
        android:clipToPadding="false"
        android:clipChildren="false">

        <RelativeLayout
            android:id="@+id/planetContainerRelativeLayout"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:clipToPadding="false"
            android:clipChildren="false">

        </RelativeLayout>

    </com.walkme.wordgalaxy.views.map.ExposedScrollView>

</RelativeLayout>
```

`ExposedScrollView` -> ScrollView with a couple exposed methods (override with public modifier) and listeners for scrolling

Comment: Try adding android:adjustViewBounds="true" or android:scaleType="fitXY"

Comment: Could you also post your xml

Comment: Is your device width is 1080?

Comment: @RaviGadipudi it doesn't have those methods (it is a normal view.. it was an ImageView but I changed to a View and forgot to update the variable name)

Comment: @Alexandr - I added the XML code, yes the device is 1080x1920 (Nexus 5)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just change your `RelativeLayout` (`android:id="@+id/parallaxContainerRelativeLayout"`) to `FrameLayout` in xml and `RelativeLayout.LayoutParams` to `FrameLayout.LayoutParams`.

Comment: When I changed to a `FrameLayout` the view kept its size, but I lost scroll capabilities. The scrollview seems to think that the layout is smaller than its bounds, is there a reason for this? Any way to fix it?

Comment: @MarcoBatista try to set layout params (width and height) of android:id="@+id/parallaxScrollView" to wrap_content

Comment: `wrap_content` didn't work, but I managed to make it work by using the `setMinimumHeight` method. Thank you very much for your help.